# How to remove the whitespace in image name and save the new file

Tags: plugins, images

I am using a wordpress plugin called "[Add Linked Images To Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-linked-images-to-gallery-v01/)" in order to save a local copy of images posted on my site. I uploaded all my files in a different hosting and I was testing this plugin in localhost to see if it does the job .

**What does this plugin do** : 
The plugin searches for external images posted in the site , save a local copy and replace the old image address in HTML code with the new image address which is in the local.

**What is the problem** : 
 
While testing the plugin in the local host , I noticed that this plugin does not correctly save images which have "white spaces" on their file names. For example :

> This is an Image.png

will not display in the blog, instead this is the correct way to show it :

> This%2520is%2520an%2520image.png

as you can see , the white spaces are replaced with "%2520" , I am not sure why this is happening, but the image wont show up in the blog.

I tried to modify this plugin so it automatically replaces the white space in the image file with "_" , I look at the source code and found this line:

```
    $content = preg_replace('/(<img[^>]* src=[\'"]?)('.$trans.')/', '$1'.$imgpath, $content);
```

which I believe is responsible for the replacing images, but when I modified it , it removed the post content and image.

Is it possible to modify this plugin, so it replace the white space in the file name first , then save a local copy, then use that local copy in the blog ?

thanks

Comment: That piece of code is to remove everiting from an image tag <img src="example.com"> and get the url, nothing to do with the file name

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sanitize_file_name( $filename )`](http://queryposts.com/function/sanitize_file_name/). This function doesn't just catch white space, it removes other special characters too:

```
$special_chars = array(
    "?", "[", "]", "/", "\\", "=", "<", ">", ":", ";", ",", 
    "'", "\"", "&", "$", "#", "*", "(", ")", "|", "~", "`", 
    "!", "{", "}", chr(0)
);
```

Find the following line in the plugin's code:

```
$id = media_handle_sideload($file_array, $post_id, $desc);
```

Immediately above this line add:

```
$file_array['tmp_name'] = sanitize_file_name( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
```

Caveat: I haven't tested it.

Make sure to rename the plugin and the plugin's file name. Otherwise you get upgrade notices. And contact the [author](http://profiles.wordpress.org/bbqiguana/), ask him to implement these changes.

Comment: should I place this code in the theme function or in the plugin? thanks

Comment: I just realized this function is included in wordpress, the question is where should I use this function so it replaces the whitespaces with dash before that plugin save it in a local storage.

Comment: @Dave See my update.

Comment: thanks again for the respond - I tried the code but unfortunately it still save the image with whitespaces in the name, and the picture wont show up on the site,

Comment: any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
rename($file_array['tmp_name'], $file_array['tmp_name'] . $ext);
```

With:

```
$newname = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $file_array['tmp_name']));
rename($file_array['tmp_name'], $newname . $ext);
```

**Not tested**

Comment: unfortunately it did not work, it still save the image with the whitespaces in the file name, and does not replace it with a dash line